# When I use spring integrationi, I can't forwad a request through firewall

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Our company want build a soft gateway to controll request. and our company alreay have a hardware firewall.
I try to use spring integration to forward a http request.
the code is very simple,only have xml file.

```
<int:channel id="searchRequestChannel" />
<int:channel id="searchReplyChannel" />
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="searchRequestInboundGateway"
                      supported-methods="GET"
                      request-channel="searchRequestChannel"
                      reply-channel="searchReplyChannel"
                      path="/services/outrequest"
                      reply-timeout="5000"
/>
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="searchServiceGateway"
                       http-method="GET"
                       request-channel="searchRequestChannel"
                       url="${forward.path}"
                       extract-request-payload="false"
                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                       reply-timeout="5000"
                       charset="UTF-8"
 />
```

the code runs well in the other network ,but when it runs in our company's inner network,some website shows time out error. But if I vist the website directly, it runs well.
So I want to known if the spring integration add something to my reqeust?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to trace those request over the network. For example using Wireshark tool. This way you'll see all the meta-data sent by that `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` and after consulting with the firewall, you should see what is wrong or extra and has to be adjusted on the firewall or in that Spring Integration config.